# Events will not fire that have been added to dynamically created divs

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm working in JavaScript. For the most part I've been able to add event listeners fine, but for divs that I have generated dynamically whatever event I add to them nothing seems to happen. The code is:

```
 for(var i=0; i<sceneNumber; i++){
    var a=i;
    if(i>2)
        a=i%3;
    sceneArray[i]=document.createElement('div');
    sceneArray[i].className="border"+a;
    if(i%2==1)
        sceneArray[i].style.left=0;
    else
        sceneArray[i].style.left=(i+1)*100;
    sceneArray[i].style.top = i*100+100;
    sceneArray[i].onclick= function(){console.log("fire212");
                                      if(extend1){
                                          console.log("scenelistener");
                                          currentArrow.rotate(degrees);
                                        currentArrow.scale(desiredLength/arrowLength,1);
                                      }
                                     };
console.log(sceneArray[i].onclick);
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(sceneArray[i]);
    sceneArray[i].style.zIndex =  -1;
    console.log(sceneArray[i]);
    }
```

As you can see I should at least get "fire212" in the console but even that doesn't happen. What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should implement something similer to JQuery's live() or on() methods. The below post may help you.

http://www.alfajango.com/blog/exploring-jquery-live-and-die/

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks for the help. I'll get back to you if it works (have some other stuff to do now).

Comment: doesn't seem to have worked. Also as you can see I generated the divs before i added the event listener, so the problem isn't that I'm adding an event listener to something that doesn't exist yet, its that my generated divs don't seem to want to obey the eventlistener

Comment: turns out I didn't give you guys enough information, I had also added a raphael object and the divs were behind it, so they couldn't be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0; i<sceneNumber; i++){
    var a=i;
    if(i>2)
        a=i%3;
    sceneArray[i]=document.createElement('div');
    sceneArray[i].className="border"+a;
    if(i%2==1)
        sceneArray[i].style.left=0;
    else
        sceneArray[i].style.left=(i+1)*100;
    sceneArray[i].style.top = i*100+100;
    sceneArray[i].onclick=onclickevent();
console.log(sceneArray[i].onclick);
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(sceneArray[i]);
    sceneArray[i].style.zIndex =  -1;
    console.log(sceneArray[i]);
    }
 function onclickevent(){
           console.log("fire212");
           if(extend1){
           console.log("scenelistener");
           currentArrow.rotate(degrees);
           currentArrow.scale(desiredLength/arrowLength,1);
           }
         }
```

Comment: turns out I didn't give you guys enough information, I had also added a raphael object and the divs were behind it, so they couldn't be clicked.